# Button Click and Listener in xamarin issue

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am a bit confused on the below code. I have the following method `DetectAvailableBeacons()` in a class called **BeaconDetector.cs** in my **Droid** implementation as follows:

```
    public void DetectAvailableBeacons()
    {
        _monitorNotifier = new MonitorNotifier();

        _rangeNotifier = new RangeNotifier();

        _tagRegion = new Region("NewRegion",null, null, null);

        _beaconManager.Bind(this);

        _rangeNotifier.DidRangeBeaconsInRegionComplete += RangingBeaconsInRegionComplete;

    }
```

Further in my PCL, the above method is defined in an Interface and I have called the above method via a dependency service inside a button clicked event as follows:

```
public void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {

beaconDetection = DependencyService.Get<IBeaconLocator>();
beaconDetection.DetectAvailableBeacons();
}
```

My question is whether the listener `_rangeNotifier.DidRangeBeaconsInRegionComplete += RangingBeaconsInRegionComplete` will keep running once I click the button ? Else, how can I make it to keep running after each 30 seconds? Please advise.

Comment: The handler `RangingBeaconsInRegionComplete` will run whenever the event `DidRangeBeaconsInRegionComplete` is triggered. Why would you want to run it every 30secs?

Comment: As it detects beacons in range, I want to run it every 30secs to get the beacons after each 30 secs. So basically what you are saying is that `RangingBeaconsInRegionComplete` triggers whenever the method `DetectAvailableBeacons()` is fired upon the button click ?

Comment: No I am not saying that. I am saying that whenever `DidRangeBeaconsInRegionComplete` is triggered, it will call your handler `RangingBeaconsInRegionComplete`.

Comment: That's what I am asking. When is `DidRangeBeaconsInRegionComplete` triggered then ?

Comment: I have never used the library and no documentation exists. According to [this sample](https://www.csharpcodi.com/vs2/896/Android-AltBeacon-Library/Samples/Forms/AltBeaconLibrary.Sample/Android/Services/AltBeaconService.cs/), it seems you would need to set it up using the BeaconManager. That is all I could find.